# How to allow certain literals in wysiwyg without being encoded

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor as an email template editor for a crm.
The point is that i want it to have certain literals to avoid being encoded, namely `<?= $somevariable ?>`

So, what I want is for the user to be able to enter text in the wysiwyg editor like

Hello `<?= $contact->full_name ?>`!

and keep the `<?= $contact->full_name ?>` as a literal without being encoded.

I may just replace all the `&lt;?=[variable regex]?&gt;` before sending it to the view, but I find it an ugly solution, I'd prefer the user have the possibility of adding the tags himself.
Security is not a concern in this specific environment, and ease of development to reduce costs is.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `<?= $contact->full_name ?>` to be visible in wysiwyg view then the angle brackets must be converted into HTML entities, otherwise they are treated as HTML markup and pushed behind the scenes. The only way I've found to get around this is to apply some post-processing. You could hook into ckeditor's *save* event (or the PHP form handling page) and apply a regex like you've suggested to convert the HTML entities back to angle brackets.

Comment: Yup, that's the best solution i've come up with also, but i hope there is a way to hook up with the way ckeditor converts things back and forth from html to avoid having to pre/post process the rich text.